# How to clear and set content for ScrollView dynamically?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am new to Android development and I struggled so much with my `ScrollView`, actually I wanna do the following:

- set its content to one of my layouts, example: `scrollView.setContent(R.layout.activity_payment)`
- clear its content, example: `scrollView.clearContent()`

Can someone tell me the codes on how to acheive the above statements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually it is pretty simple:

Override the `ScrollView`:

```
public class ClearScrollView extends ScrollView
```

Add two methods:

```
public void setContent(@LayoutRes int layoutRes) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(layoutRes, this, false);
    this.addView(view);
}

public void clearContent() {
    this.removeAllViews();
}
```

And that is all. Use your ScrollView everywhere there is a need.